# Powershell Loop and While Optimization

Tags: loops, powershell, time, while-loop

I have created a script to restart on a predetermined time period.  Unfortunately, while it's checking the time I run into cpu usage issues.  It just runs and runs (Suppose this is the essence of a while loop).  I'm looking for a better way to do this.

So basically I have it setup to have times that it looks for, for example: 12:00

I then run a while and it keeps running until it hits 12:00 and then executes some things and runs again to the next time interval.

Interestingly enough it escaped my mind while creating this that it would be a resource hog and extremely inefficient.

So my question presents itself as to what should I do if I want to restart something on certain intervals, but not want it to check every second/ millisecond.

This would be restarting a gameserver process and the timing is critical because people need warning in game.

I will include the script for viability.

```
$CurrentTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%R"

$debug = "true" 

$Times = "12:00", "13:00", "01:00", "14:12"
$servers = "Notepad"
$aff = "C4", "38"  

$scriptRun = 0
$serverCount = 1

$startedServers

$loop = 1

function checkServers 
{
    if ($debug -eq "true") { Write-Output "Entering Loop ::: $loop" }
    while($loop -eq 1) 
    {

    if ($CurrentTime -eq $Times[1] -or $CurrentTime -eq $Times[2] -or $CurrentTime -eq $Times[3] -or $CurrentTime -eq $Times[4]) 
    {
        stopServers
        foreach($i in $servers)
        {
            if ($debug -eq "true") { Write-Output "The Server being started is $server" }
            startServer( [ref]$servers[$i] )
        }
        $loop = 0
    } else {
        $loop = 1
        checkServers
    }
    }
}

function waits 
{
    Start-Sleep -seconds 61
    $loop = 1
    checkServers
}

function stopServers 
{
    if ($scriptRun -eq 1)
    {
        foreach ($i in $startedServers)
        {
            Stop-Process -processname $startedServers[$i]
            Write-Output "$startedServers[$i] has been stopped"  
        }
    } else {
    Write-Output "Starting Servers for the first time"
    }   
}

function startServer( [ref]$server ) 
{
    $server = $server 

    Start $server 
    $s = "$server.exe"
    $instances = Get-Process $s

    foreach ($s in $instances) {
        $s.ProcessAffinity = $aff[$serverCount]
        $serverCount = $serverCount + 1 
    }

    if ($scriptRun -eq 0) {
        $startedServers += $s
        $scriptRun = 1 
    }
    waits
    Write-Output "$server was successfully started at $CurrentTime" 
}

Write-Output "Starting RestartServer at $CurrentTime"
checkServers
```

**Yes there are probably other errors and I am working through the most obvious one first then will get to the others.

Comment: If you are only wanting to execute tasks at specific times, why not  use a scheduled task instead to just trigger at the times you want.

Comment: I was hoping to create a stand alone script separate from windows task scheduler, but you're probably right in that this would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking every second is not a big deal as long as the check is not CPU intensive.  However when you have a tight loop that is continuously checking - that is a problem.  Just put in a Start-Sleep -sec 1 or Start-Sleep -Milli 500 and that should lighten the load on the CPU dramatically.  You can also use a scheduled job to run script at pre-determined times.

Comment: technically this would work as it doesn't check seconds I could even extend it to check only every say 55 seconds and it should still catch it correctly.  thanks not sure why I didn't think of this.